# How to debug android devices in remote desktop in xamarin?

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, remote-desktop

I need to find out how we can debug in xamarin using remote desktop.

I have xamarin installed in my remote machine and my scenario is, I will be using physical device in my local windows machine.

So if I connect the android device in my local machine, it should get detected in my remote desktop and I can also able to debug. How we can achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: is your remote machine and local machine is in the same network?

Comment: Perry Qian-MSFT  The information you provided applies to Windows desktop applications and ASP.NET applications. My requirement is for xamarin in Visual studio

Comment: @SupunLiyanaarachchi No If it is in the same network then I can use WIFI debugging. I need to find can we access the USB ports from my local to Remote machine through Remote Desktop Connection. Is there any settings to enable like this?

Answer (score 0):

> How to debug android devices in remote desktop in xamarin?

**I am afraid that you cannot get what you want for Visual Studio 2015.**

For VS2015, remote debugger cannot debug Xamarin projects.

**However**, if you have VS2017 or VS2019, you can use [RevDeBug VS extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RevDeBug.RecordReplayforNET-RevDeBug) to debug your xamarin project remotely.

You can refer to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W734uOQXj-s).

Comment: it is pretty expensive thought. 1K dollar per month is unbelievable price.